# mousewheel event triggered on ipad chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, google-chrome

I have 2 event listeners like so:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheel, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheel, false);
```

Both trigger the same function `mouseWheel`. This works perfectly on desktop and laptop browsers. On ipad or touch devices, these events should not trigger because they are touch scroll events, not mouse wheel. In iPad Safari, the events do not trigger as expected. However in iPad Chrome, the events DO trigger. This is unwanted behaviour. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's not simple](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/) to feature detect if the device is touch enabled.

As the article suggests, you could try this:

```
var hasTouch = false;

window.addEventListener('touchstart',function setHasTouch(){
  hasTouch = true;
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', setHasTouch);
});
```

Then check if device is touch enabled before you execute the mouseWheel function:

```
window.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheel, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheel, false);

function mouseWheel() {
  if (hasTouch) return false;
  // Your code
}
```